# Adding custom CSS to element when unobtrusive validation failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to add a CSS class to a textbox when validation fails.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AdminUser.Username, new
{
    @id = "Username",
    @name = "Username",
    @type = "text",
    @class = "form-control",
    @placeholder = "Kullanıcı Adı",
    @autocomplete = "off"
})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AdminUser.Username, null, new { @class = "text-danger text-12 pl-10" })
```

Is it possible to add a callback to it? Or anyway else?

**Solution for me:**

Overriding onError class of unobtrusive validation source js did the trick. Now I can able to access upper div element.

```
    if (replace) {
        container.empty();
        error.removeClass("input-validation-error").appendTo(container);
        error.closest("div").addClass("has-error");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` will be added with `input-validation-error` class when the validation fails. So you can override that class like this with your custom styles:

```
.input-validation-error {
    // your styles
}
```

If you add the above `style` to your page it will affect all inputs. So, if you want to target specific elements, you can add a `custom-error-message` class

```
.custom-error-message.input-validation-error{
    // error styles
}
```

And then in the `TextBox` you want to target:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AdminUser.Username, new { @class = "custom-error-message form-control"})
```

Now your custom error styles will be added only to those with inputs with `custom-error-message` class.

Comment: Thanks for your advice adiga. But what I'm trying to do is running a function or overwrite existing one. Not overriding CSS class.

Comment: @AlparslanParlak This will overwrite the default CSS